# Undoing a strip_tags in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to customize a Word press template and having some trouble. The page is http://rexonmedia.com/?page_id=113 and under each section there are description, all the text in description is plain text(Actionscript, Visit site ...). I want the text to be formatted or have links like the source (http://rexonmedia.com/?portfolio=audiomaya) with hyperlink.

I came to find out that the culprit here is "strip_tags" tags. It's used on two different places. I tried couple of scenarios but didn't work. Please help

```
   public function customFormat($content,$strip_tags = false,$shortcode=true){
   $content =   stripslashes($content);
   if($shortcode)
   $content = do_shortcode( shortcode_unautop( $content ) ); 
   $content = preg_replace('#^<\/p>|^<br\s?\/?>|<p>$|<p>\s*(&nbsp;)?\s*<\/p>#', '', $content);

   if($strip_tags)
     $content = strip_tags($content,"<hades>,<tabend>");

   return $content;

    }
```

---

```
<?php  
global $more;    // Declare global $more (before the loop).
    $more = 1;
$content = get_the_content('');
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
$this->shortenContent( $content_limit ,  strip_tags( $content  ) ); 
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You cannot undo a `strip_tags`.

Comment: @andrewsi I think rex is asking if there is a way to undo strip_tags. There is nothing in the php manual page for [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to revert the changes.

Comment: ANd there can't be. Once something is eliminated there's no sane way to restore it, unless you start parsing all possible html keywords to add back the tags, and this adds mess to the mess.

Comment: @le_garry That's kinda what I thought. But since he's posted the code, he can access the PHP; so surely he can just comment out those lines? Clearly, I need more coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Supply strip_tags with the allowable tags. The line in the first block of code would change to:

```
$content = strip_tags($content,"<strong><a>");
```

And the line in the second block of code would change to:

```
$this->shortenContent( $content_limit ,  strip_tags( $content, "<strong><a>" ) );
```

By the way, the function defines $strip_tags as false in the function definition if it is not supplied. Check that!

```
public function customFormat($content,$strip_tags = false,$shortcode=true){
```

Comment: Beware of attributes: if taking HTML from an untrusted source, strip_tags will let attributes slip by. Ex: onmouseover='window.location=derp' will go through.

Comment: in his case, it appears to be that only the admins can post these comments, so you shouldn't worry. Also, that problem has to do with strip_tags in general, not my answer.

Comment: Absolutely. +1'd for an apt answer, but making sure there's a warning, if someone reuses the solution for a different circumstance.

Comment: I tried all three suggestion but still didn't work. When I tried $this->shortenContent( $content_limit ,  strip_tags( $content, "<strong>,<a>" ) ); 
 it throws some error.

Comment: Is there other functions that will convert html text into a regular text?

Comment: What about the following what does it do? -----    $content = preg_replace('#^<\/p>|^<br\s?\/?>|<p>$|<p>\s*(&nbsp;)?\s*<\/p>#', '', $content);

Comment: it replaces other stuff like spaces and paragraphs. Which error do you get? By the way, I only gave 2 suggestions, not three. You're probably need to read better. I made a typo in my code, please try again. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks ed. I came with a different solution. I put in <?php the_content(); ?> Wordpress code that shows everything without stripping out any details. Exactly, what I was looking for. Thank you for you help.